# How can I Add a tag in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a a tag in `frontpage-course-list div` but, the below code will add class in `frontpage-course-list div`.

```
    $( "#frontpage-course-list" ).add( "a" ).addClass( "myclass" );
    var pdiv = $( "#frontpage-course-list" ).add( "a" );
```

Please let me know how to add

Comment: You should mark an answer as accepted if there is an answer that helped you to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use append:

```
 $( "#frontpage-course-list" ).append("<a class='myclass'>My custom link</a>");
```

If you want an img inside a you can do

```
$( "#frontpage-course-list" ).append("<a class='myclass'><img src='/path/to/image'></a>");
```

Or if you want an image (not a link) you can write the following:

```
$( "#frontpage-course-list" ).append("<img src='/path/to/image'>");
```

Comment: $("#frontpage-course-list").append("<a class='yourclass'><img src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/elfin28/pix/images/chat.png" /></a>")

Comment: Can I add an image tag in between a tag

Answer (score 2):

Use append

```
$("#frontpage-course-list").append("<a class='yourclass'></a>");
```

This will add the anchor as last child of that specified element(`frontpage-course-list`).

If you want to add the anchor as firt child, then use `prepend`

```
$("#frontpage-course-list").prepend("<a class='yourclass'></a>");
```

You can also try something like,

```
var anchor = $("<a/>", {
    'class': 'yourclass',
    'href': 'your href'
});
$("#frontpage-course-list").append(anchor);
```

Comment: $("#frontpage-course-list").append("<a class='yourclass'><img src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/elfin28/pix/images/chat.png" /></a>");

Comment: Can I add an image tag in between a tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new anchor element with the said class then add it to the div then you can use

```
$('<a />', {
    'class': 'myclass'
}).appendTo('#frontpage-course-list')
```

The [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) will return a jQuery object which contain the elements in the calling set and the elements returned by the passing selector.

Comment: $("#frontpage-course-list").append("<a class='yourclass'><img src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/elfin28/pix/images/chat.png" /></a>")

Comment: Can I add an image tag in between a tag

Answer (score 0):

The following will not save the added elements, because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set in `pdiv` unchanged:

```
  $( "#frontpage-course-list" ).add( "a" ).addClass( "myclass" );
  var pdiv = $( "#frontpage-course-list" ).add( "a" );// WRONG, pdiv will not change.
```

To over come this, use `.append`.

```
 $("#frontpage-course-list").append("<a class='myclass'></a>");
```

*[Reference DOC](https://api.jquery.com/add/)*

Comment: $("#frontpage-course-list").append("<a class='yourclass'><img src="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/elfin28/pix/images/chat.png" /></a>");

Comment: Can I add an image tag in between a tag

Comment: @KabirKhan : Yes, you can do.